# How to display definition list from text file using php

Tags: php

I have a definition list of movie credits in a text file.  I used a `preg_split` to read and separate the file with the following line:

`$infoLines= preg_split( "/\n|:/", file_get_contents(getPath($dir,"info.txt")));`

I need to display the contents of this file with each even numbered index will have a `<dt>` tag while every odd numbered index will have a `<dd>` tag. I am trying to do this by using a foreach loop.

I found a tutorial site with the following example

```
$movie = array( "title" => "Rear Window",
            "director" => "Alfred Hitchcock",
            "year" => 1954,
            "minutes" => 112 );

echo "<dl>";

foreach ( $movie as $key => $value ) {
echo "<dt>$key:</dt>";
echo "<dd>$value</dd>";
}

echo "</dl>";
```

Which prints:

```
title:
    Rear Window
director:
    Alfred Hitchcock
year:
    1954
minutes:
    112
```

I tried to incorporate something like this into my code and I couldn't get it to work since I am reading from a file and not setting the array/key manually.

```
function DisplayInfo($dir){
  $infoLines= preg_split( "/\n|:/", file_get_contents(getPath($dir, "info.txt")) );


  echo "<dl>";
  foreach ($infoLines as $key => $value) {
     echo"<dt>$key</dt>";
     echo"<dd>$value</dd>";
  }
  echo "</dl>";
}
```

My output is:

```
0
    STARRING
1
    Cary Elwes, Robin Wright, Andre the Giant, Mandy Patinkin
2
    DIRECTOR
3
    Rob Reiner
```

But I need:

```
STARRING
    Cary Elwes, Robin Wright, Andre the Giant, Mandy Patinkin

DIRECTOR
    Rob Reiner
```

I feel like I am almost there and have just hit a dead end. How can I properly display definition lists in PHP?

There are plenty of examples such as the one I posted but none dealing with information from txt files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code I'm assuming a line in your file looks something like

```
DIRECTOR:Rob Reiner
```

In which case, you shouldn't be splitting the line data until you are ready to print.

```
function DisplayInfo($dir){
  $infoLines= file(getPath($dir, "info.txt"));
  echo "<dl>";
  foreach ($infoLines as $line) {
     list($key, $value) = explode(':', $line, 2); 
     echo"<dt>$key</dt>";
     echo"<dd>$value</dd>";
  }
  echo "</dl>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you! worked like a charm, however I did have to make a small change to `list($key, $value) = explode(':', $line, 2);`

Comment: @ScruffyNerfherder sorry about missing the `list`! I'll edit the answer so that it's correct for anyone else that finds it.